# Scheduled query not appending any rows

Tags: google-bigquery

Ihave scheduled query to refresh an existing BQ table. BQ says the job runs, and confirms the time it finished.

However, the rows never actually get appended.

There are no sorts of errors or anything firing.

The table even says it was last modified at the same time that the scheduled query runs.

The write type is write append.

Anyone experience this issue? Thank you

```
select event_date,event_timestamp,user_id,event_name,value,
row_number() over (order by event_timestamp,event_date,event_name) as index
from 
(
select *,row_number() over (order by event_timestamp,event_date,event_name) as id
from (select  event_date,event_timestamp,
(select params.value.string_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="user_id") as user_id,
case when event_name= "UAccountBalanceUpdated" 
and params1.key="account_type" and params1.value.string_value="Gems"  
and params2.key="product" and params2.value.string_value="GEM_PACK" then "GemsBought" 

when event_name= "UAccountBalanceUpdated" 
and params1.key="account_type" and params1.value.string_value="Gems"  
and params2.key="product" and params2.value.string_value="Room ticket" then "RoomJoined"  


-- when event_name= "UAccountBalanceUpdated" 
-- and params1.key="account_type" and params1.value.string_value="winnings"  
-- and params2.key="product" and params2.value.string_value="GAME_WINNINGS" then "RoomWon"  

when event_name= "UAccountBalanceUpdated" 
and params1.key="account_type" and params1.value.string_value="Gems"  
and params2.key="product" and params2.value.string_value="ROOM_CANCEL_REFUND" then "RoomCancelledRefund" 


when event_name= "UAccountBalanceUpdated" 
and params1.key="account_type" and params1.value.string_value="Gems"  
and params2.key="category" and params2.value.string_value="Bonus" then "WelcomeGemsOffered" 

when event_name= "UPaymentTransactionUpdate" 
and params1.key="reason" and params1.value.string_value="Purchase"  
and params2.key="status" and params2.value.string_value="Success" then "Cashin" 

when event_name= "UPaymentTransactionUpdate" 
and params1.key="reason" and params1.value.string_value="Withdrawal"  
and params2.key="status" and params2.value.string_value="Success" then "Cashout" 

when event_name= "URoomRegistered" 
and params1.key="entry_fee_currency" and params1.value.string_value="Gem"  
and params2.key="is_success" and params2.value.int_value=1 then "RoomJoined" 


when event_name= "UWon" 
and params1.key="entry_fee_currency" and params1.value.string_value="GEM"
and params2.key="rank" and params2.value.int_value>-1 
then "RoomWon"

when event_name= "ULoggedIn" 
and params1.key="event_source" and params1.value.string_value="Server"
and params2.key="is_new_user" and params2.value.int_value>-1 
then "Loggedin" 

when event_name= "RoomConcluded" 
and params1.key="rewards_config_name" and params1.value.string_value="REFUND"  
and params2.key="entry_fee_currency" and params2.value.string_value="GEM" then "RoomCancelled"  


when event_name= "RoomConcluded" 
and params1.key="rewards_config_name" and params1.value.string_value<>"REFUND"  
and params2.key="entry_fee_currency" and params2.value.string_value="GEM" then "RoomConcluded"  



when event_name= "UPlayedGame" 
and params1.key="entry_fee_currency" and params1.value.string_value="GEM"
and params2.key="prize_currency" and params2.value.string_value="INR" 
then "UserPlayerGame"  


else Null end  as event_name,




case 
when event_name= "UAccountBalanceUpdated" 
and params1.key="account_type" and params1.value.string_value="Gems"  
and params2.key="product" and params2.value.string_value="GEM_PACK" 
then (select params.value.float_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="amount") 



when event_name= "UAccountBalanceUpdated" 
and params1.key="account_type" and params1.value.string_value="Gems"  
and params2.key="product" and params2.value.string_value="Room ticket" then 
(select params.value.float_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="amount") 



-- when event_name= "UAccountBalanceUpdated" 
-- and params1.key="account_type" and params1.value.string_value="winnings"  
-- and params2.key="product" and params2.value.string_value="GAME_WINNINGS" then 
-- (select params.value.float_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="amount") 


when event_name= "UAccountBalanceUpdated" 
and params1.key="account_type" and params1.value.string_value="Gems"  
and params2.key="product" and params2.value.string_value="ROOM_CANCEL_REFUND" then 
(select params.value.float_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="amount") 

when event_name= "UAccountBalanceUpdated" 
and params1.key="account_type" and params1.value.string_value="Gems"  
and params2.key="category" and params2.value.string_value="Bonus" then 
(select params.value.float_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="amount") 

when event_name= "UPaymentTransactionUpdate" 
and params1.key="reason" and params1.value.string_value="Purchase"  
and params2.key="status" and params2.value.string_value="Success" then 
(select params.value.float_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="amount") 

when event_name= "UPaymentTransactionUpdate" 
and params1.key="reason" and params1.value.string_value="Withdrawal"  
and params2.key="status" and params2.value.string_value="Success" then 
(select params.value.float_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="amount") 


when event_name= "URoomRegistered" 
and params1.key="entry_fee_currency" and params2.value.string_value="Gem"  
and params2.key="is_success" and params2.value.int_value=1
then 
(select params.value.float_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="entry_fee") 


when event_name= "UWon" 
and params1.key="entry_fee_currency" and params1.value.string_value="GEM"
and params2.key="rank" and params2.value.int_value>-1 
then 
(select params.value.float_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="prize_amount") 


when event_name= "ULoggedIn" 
and params1.key="event_source" and params1.value.string_value="Server"
and params2.key="is_new_user" and params2.value.int_value>-1 
then 
(select params.value.int_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="is_new_user") 

when event_name= "RoomConcluded" 
and params1.key="rewards_config_name" and params1.value.string_value="REFUND"  
and params2.key="entry_fee_currency" and params2.value.string_value="GEM" then 
(select params.value.float_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="min_players") 



when event_name= "RoomConcluded" 
and params1.key="rewards_config_name" and params1.value.string_value<>"REFUND"  
and params2.key="entry_fee_currency" and params2.value.string_value="GEM" then 
(select params.value.int_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="players_count") 



when event_name= "UPlayedGame" 
and params1.key="entry_fee_currency" and params1.value.string_value="GEM"
and params2.key="prize_currency" and params2.value.string_value="INR" 
then (select params.value.int_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="game_score") 


else Null end  as value

FROM `analytics_193614062.server_events` ,
UNNEST(event_params) as params1,
UNNEST(event_params) as params2) where event_name is not null
and PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',  event_date)= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)    


UNION ALL

select *,row_number() over (order by event_timestamp,event_date,event_name) as id
from (select  event_date,event_timestamp, user_id,

case 
when event_name= "user_engagement" 
and params.key="firebase_event_origin" and params.value.string_value="auto"  
then "user_engagement" 

when event_name= "RankFetched" 
and params.key="is_success" and params.value.int_value=1
then "RankFetched" 

when event_name= "BuyGemsInitiated" 
and params.key="gems_entry_type" and params.value.string_value="GEM_PACK"
then "BuyGemsInitiated" 


when event_name= "app_remove" 
and params.key="firebase_event_origin" and params.value.string_value="auto"
then "app_remove" 


when event_name= "first_open" 
and params.key="firebase_event_origin" and params.value.string_value="auto"
then "first_open" 

when event_name= "FTUECompleted" 
and params.key="event_source" and params.value.string_value="Client"
then "FTUECompleted"

else Null end  as event_name,

case 
when event_name= "user_engagement" 
and params.key="firebase_event_origin" and params.value.string_value="auto"  
then (select params.value.int_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="engagement_time_msec") 


when event_name= "RankFetched" 
and params.key="is_success" and params.value.int_value=1
then (select params.value.int_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="current_score") 

when event_name= "BuyGemsInitiated" 
and params.key="gems_entry_type" and params.value.string_value="GEM_PACK"
then (select params.value.int_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="gem_balance") 


when event_name= "app_remove" 
and params.key="firebase_event_origin" and params.value.string_value="auto"
then (select params.value.int_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="ga_session_number") 


when event_name= "first_open" 
and params.key="firebase_event_origin" and params.value.string_value="auto"
then (select params.value.int_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="previous_first_open_count") 

when event_name= "FTUECompleted" 
and params.key="event_source" and params.value.string_value="Client"
then (select params.value.int_value from unnest(event_params) as params where params.key="score") 

else Null end  as value


FROM `analytics_193614062.events_*` ,
UNNEST(event_params) as params
where _TABLE_SUFFIX =FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))

) 
where event_name is not null

) order by event_date
```

Comment: show the query!

Comment: I have added the query.It fetches data for the last day. I choose option to append to the existing table when I reschedule the query.

Comment: are you getting any output if you run it manually?

Comment: yes I am getting perfect output. Infact I used this query (by adding insert statement) to backfill.

Comment: Should I use insert statement even in the scheduled query? The docs don't say about using insert because there is already an option for appending

Comment: add project to the table reference - `project.dataset.table`

Comment: Hey Mikhail, thanks. I have included project name to check if it fixes the issue. Also, I have noticed that I cannot schedule the query on the same day. Whenever I do that, the scheduled query runs from the next day.

Comment: Please clarify - is it fixed by adding project to table reference?

Comment: I have added the project name but cannot check if it is fixed since the min scheduled date is tomorrow. I am unable to make that today in the scheduler.

Comment: I see. Please let us know tomorrow :o)

Comment: Sure, Mikhail. I will

Comment: Hey Mikhail, using project id solves this problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add project to the table reference - `project.dataset.table`